# WPF Multi-Threading and rotating image

Tags: wpf, vb.net, multithreading

This one has driven me nuts for long enough.

Start a background thread to download data from a webservice on a new thread then show an image on the status bar and change the text.

I have tried with Dispatcher (with each priority) but nothing happens until the threaded sub completes. The closest I can get is implementing the equivalent of DoEvents that at least loads the image and the text, but then the image stops spinning until the thread completes.

Any ideas?

```
Public Sub Return_DT(ByVal TableName As String)

    CurrentDT = TableName
    If DownloadingDS Is Nothing Then
        DownloadingDS = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    End If
    If DownloadingDS.ContainsKey(TableName) = False Then
        DownloadingDS.Add(TableName, "Loading")
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Select Case TableName
        Case "A_Documents"
            strSQL = "SELECT Document_ID, Account_Type, Account_No, Document_Description, Accounts_Only, Open_Editing, Editing_Name, Updated_Name, Updated FROM A_Documents"
        Case Else
            strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & TableName
    End Select
    ' Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, CType(Sub() LoadMetroImage(), SendOrPostCallback), Nothing)
    'Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, CType(Sub() ChangeLeftStatusText("Downloading " & CurrentDT & " data..."), SendOrPostCallback), Nothing)


            LoadMetroImage()
    ChangeLeftStatusText("Downloading " & CurrentDT & " data...")
   Application.Current.MainWindow.FindName("MainMetroStatusBar")

    Dim vWorker As New BackgroundWorker

    AddHandler vWorker.DoWork, AddressOf BackgroundDownload
    AddHandler vWorker.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf DownloadCompleted
    vWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
    DoEvents()

    End Sub
```

This is the closest I can get

```
 Public Sub DoEvents()
    Dim frame As New DispatcherFrame()
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, New DispatcherOperationCallback(AddressOf ExitFrame), frame)
    Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame)
End Sub

Public Function ExitFrame(ByVal f As Object) As Object
    CType(f, DispatcherFrame).Continue = False

    Return Nothing
End Function
```

=== EDIT === How Return_DT is called

```
Public Function DT_Return(ByVal DT As DataTable, ByVal TableName As String) As DataTable
    Try
        If Not DT Is Nothing Then
            If DT_CheckUpdated(TableName) = True Then
                Return DT
            Else
                Return_DT(TableName)
                vService = New Service1Client
                Dim DS As DataSet = vService.ReturnDataSet("SELECT * FROM " & TableName, Current_HOA_ID)
                Dim vDT As DataTable = DS.Tables(0).Copy
                DS.Dispose()
                Return vDT
            End If




        Else
            Return_DT(TableName)
            vService = New Service1Client
            Dim DS As DataSet = vService.ReturnDataSet("SELECT * FROM " & TableName, Current_HOA_ID)
            Dim vDT As DataTable = DS.Tables(0).Copy
            DS.Dispose()
            Return vDT


        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex)
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Do you interact with the UI in `BackgroundDownload`?

Comment: Hi Pragmateek - I have tried dispatcher from the background thread (didn't do anything) but, of course, no direct interaction with the UI

Comment: Which component do you use for the download, a WebClient?

Comment: Web Service - even using that in Async mode I still have the same problem

Comment: And I guess `Return_DT` is directly invoked from an event handler?

Comment: Called from code like - Dim vDT as DataTable = Return_DT(A_Nominal_DT, "A_Nominal") - the point is no matter what I run in a background thread the problem is the same

Comment: Sorry - called from a function DT_Return (as per edit in the main text above)

Comment: Can you make a minimal example that illustrates the issue?

Comment: I think I have just spotted the problem :-) Just trying to find a workaround

Comment: Here is the issue - a check is made first to see is the DataTable exists - if it does another check is made to see if the backend DB has been updated - if the answers are Yes and No it returns the DataTable in memory, if not it downloads one in the background (that is working) BUT is returning a current one at the same time using the UI thread. I need to find a way to free up the thread until the background one is downloaded and then use that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution was to use Dispatcher.Timer in the UI thread to check every second to see if the DT had been downloaded..

```
 Public Function DT_Return(ByVal DT As DataTable, ByVal TableName As String) As DataTable
    Try
        If Not DT Is Nothing Then
            If DT_CheckUpdated(TableName) = True Then
                Return DT
            Else
                CurrentlyDownloading = True
                Return_DT(TableName)
                Dim vTimer As New DispatcherTimer
                vTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)
                AddHandler vTimer.Tick, Sub(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
                                            Do While CurrentlyDownloading = True

                                            Loop

                                            vTimer.Stop()
                                        End Sub

                vTimer.Start()
                Return DT
            End If
        Else
            CurrentlyDownloading = True
            Return_DT(TableName)
            Dim vTimer As New DispatcherTimer
            vTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)
            AddHandler vTimer.Tick, Sub(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
                                        Do While CurrentlyDownloading = True

                                        Loop

                                        vTimer.Stop()
                                    End Sub

            vTimer.Start()
            Return DT

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex)
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```